# Sql JOIN Performance on Big tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, inner-join

I have a query like following line.

```
SELECT /**/ 
FROM   #Customers fia 
        INNER JOIN [FIA_CMMN_FIN_ACCOUNT]  fca WITH(NOLOCK) ON (fca.REPORT_OID=fia.OID AND fca.STATUS='1')
        INNER JOIN [FIA_CMMN_RPT_PARAMETER] pr WITH(NOLOCK) ON (pr.REPORT_OID =fia.OID AND pr.STATUS='1')
        WHERE 
        (fca.ORIGINAL_1+fca.ORIGINAL_2+fca.ORIGINAL_3+fca.ORIGINAL_4)!= 0
```

[image]

Second table "pr" has 28.000.000 rows and query progressing 2 minutes. How can i optimize query.

Comment: one way to optimize : dont select all columns, select only those columns that are needed, trust me it will have a big difference.

Comment: What is the query plan? What keys and indexes do you have?

Comment: İ could not upload query plan because of my reputation

Comment: Unfortunately, all the columns required

Comment: you can put `fca.STATUS='1'` and `pr.STATUS='1'` in where clause.

Comment: when i put status = 1 in where it taking more time

Comment: Just try like this in the where clause (( fca.ORIGINAL_1>0 or  fca.ORIGINAL_1<0) or (fca.ORIGINAL_2>0 or fca.ORIGINAL_2<0) or (fca.ORIGINAL_3>0 or fca.ORIGINAL_3<0) or (fca.ORIGINAL_4>0 or fca.ORIGINAL_4<0))

Comment: @NewUser I think that you thought `fca.ORIGINAL_1<>0 AND fca.ORIGINAL_2<>0 AND fca.ORIGINAL_3<>0 AND fca.ORIGINAL_4<>0`

Comment: Create non-clustered index for your tables.

Comment: I already have a clustered index on my temp table. other table fca has index on Report_OID column.

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sql-server-tip-category/9/performance-tuning/

Comment: im curious with the with(nolock) i stumble in this nice article `http://blog.codinghorror.com/deadlocked/`

Comment: Does your query plan suggest any indexes? What indexes do you have?

Comment: What percentage of your records would have `status=1`?

Comment: about %50 percentage